# SQL weight concept with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently use the following ranking:

```
rank as individual_product_rank, -- manually assigned value 1-7
row_number() over (partition by account_number order by rank asc) as product_priority,
```

What I want to achieve the following in MySQL:
Change the current logic to a weight concept that allows one more condition on top of the existing one above. I'd like to add a variable for order volume. If a product is has the rank of 1 and an order volume of $1,000 I want it rank higher than a product with rank 7 and order volume of $10.
How do I achieve this weight concept?

Thank you!

Comment: You add another order column with a CASE WHEN and then define your logic

Comment: is higher rank a higher product_priority?  do you want to always rank by volume, and look at the manual rank if volume is tied?  or use some formula of volume and manual rank to produce a number that determines rank?  if the latter, what is that formula?

Comment: @ysth It's the latter! - The formula should look something like this: rank volume (1-7) and weigh volume and manual rank each 50% of new_rank, the smaller the new_rank value the higher it's priority.